# Run .jar using Specific JRE in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar

I am creating a Swing based GUI application. I want to run my jar file in ubuntu. And I dont want to install JRE in my system, but I have all jre files in a folder. So if I want to run jar/class file anything, I need to specify this folder path. How to do this?

Comment: ***Why*** do you not want to install a JDK to get access to the Jar tool?

Comment: BTW - I just noted the [tag:eclipse] tag!  I'm sure Eclipse has a way to generate a runnable (with a manifest specifying the main class) Jar.

Comment: Why you are not creating the jar file on the machine where you compile your classes?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse you create a new runnable JAR file in the Eclipse workbench:

1. From the menu bar's File menu, select Export.
2. Expand the Java node and select Runnable JAR file. Click Next.
3. In the  Opens the Runnable JAR export wizard Runnable JAR File Specification page, select a 'Java Application' launch configuration to use to create a runnable JAR.
4. In the Export destination field, either type or click Browse to select a location for the JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$jar cvf sample.jar classone.class classtwo.class`

Comment: but to do this I need to have jre installed in my system.

Comment: this is the correct way to do if we have jre installed, `jar cfm JarName.jar Manifest.txt ClassName.class`
 and `Manifest.txt` sholud contain `Main-Class: ClassName`

Comment: Note to both of you.  A JRE does not contain the `jar` command.  That comes from a JDK/SDK.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yeah, thanq for correcting my mistake. But how can i run jar file without installing jre. To run jar file we need jre

Comment: What is this question about?  1) How to **create** a Jar without installing the **JDK.** 2) How  to **run** a Jar without installing the **JRE.** 3) How to **include** a **JRE** with your app. 4) ??.. -- So far I've had to try and guess what it is that you are trying to ***achieve*** here, since the question is very confusing.